# atopsar on Ubuntu 18.04 not showing disk activity

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-monitoring, atop

I run **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS** on a AWS EC2 instance (t3.large)

```
myserver:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I've installed `atop` with its default configuration except `INTERVAL` modified from `600` to `60`.

Everything is ok except the disk activity, which is **always empty** in reports displayed by `atopsar`

```
myserver:~$  atopsar -R 120 -d
myserver  4.15.0-1032-aws  #34-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 17 15:18:09 UTC 2019  x86_64  2019/07/24
-------------------------- analysis date: 2019/07/24 --------------------------
00:00:01  disk           busy read/s KB/read  writ/s KB/writ avque avserv _dsk_
02:00:01
04:00:01
06:00:01
08:00:01
10:00:01
12:00:01
14:00:01
14:21:01
```

I also run a similar AWS EC2 instance running **Ubuntu 14.04.5**:

```
myserver:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I've installed `atop` there too with the same changed configuration, and the disk activity is correctly recorded:

```
myserver  3.13.0-107-generic  #154-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 20 09:57:27 UTC 2016  x86_64  2019/07/24
-------------------------- analysis date: 2019/07/24 --------------------------
00:00:01  disk           busy read/s KB/read  writ/s KB/writ avque avserv _dsk_
02:00:01  xvda             4%   24.8    53.3    60.3    22.9   4.5   0.49 ms
04:00:01  xvda             3%    9.3    49.2    56.4    19.1   3.4   0.48 ms
06:00:01  xvda             4%   10.1    53.0    64.3    21.5   4.3   0.47 ms
08:00:01  xvda             4%   21.7    34.2    67.1    19.2   4.2   0.46 ms
10:00:01  xvda             4%   11.2    53.4    67.2    18.9   4.0   0.49 ms
12:00:01  xvda             4%   12.0    50.8    68.6    20.3   4.7   0.49 ms
14:00:01  xvda             4%   16.4    50.9    70.1    19.9   4.6   0.48 ms
14:27:01  xvda             4%   18.1    54.4    69.5    20.1   3.8   0.47 ms
```

Why is the disk activity not recorded on the first server ?

Comment: Run it under the `strace` and investigate the syscalls executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t3.* instances have their disk exposed as NVMe devices (`/dev/nvme0*`), I'm guessing the version of `atopsar` you have doesn't know to recognise them.

According to https://www.atoptool.nl/downloadatop.php version 2.4.0 claims to now recognise NVMe devices so you might want to try a newer version.

Comment: Yes, you're right: the installed version on the t3.* instances with Ubuntu 18 is 2.3.0.